# TLS/SSL Token Incorrect Expiry Dates

Tags: go, ssl

I was attempting to build a function to grab certificate information. When utilizing the top-level domain with "www" everyone works well, yet when excluding that or querying a third-level domain it provides incorrect "Not After" and "Not Before" dates.

I was wondering if anyone had a remedy or advice. Thank you!

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "www.google.com:443", conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error when Dialing", err)
        return
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    certs := conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates

    for _, cert := range certs {
        fmt.Printf("FQDNs: %s\n\n", cert.DNSNames)
        fmt.Printf("Issuer Name: %s\n\n", cert.Issuer)
        fmt.Printf("Issued: %v\n\n", cert.NotBefore.Format("Jan 2, 2006 3:04 PM"))
        fmt.Printf("Expires: %s\n\n", cert.NotAfter.Format("Jan 2, 2006 3:04 PM"))
        fmt.Printf("Issuer Common Name: %s\n\n", cert.Issuer.CommonName)
        fmt.Println("-----------------------------------------")
    }
}
```

Comment: "when excluding that or querying a third-level domain it provides incorrect "Not After" and "Not Before" dates"  Querying *what* domain?  Querying *how*?  Please post a **complete** example.

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {

    address := "google.com"
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", address+":443", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Server doesn't support SSL certificate err: " + err.Error())
    }

    err = conn.VerifyHostname(address)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Hostname doesn't match with certificate: " + err.Error())
    }
    certs := conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates

    for _, cert := range certs {
        fmt.Printf("FQDNs: %s\n\n", cert.DNSNames)
        fmt.Printf("Issuer Name: %s\n\n", cert.Issuer)
        fmt.Printf("Issued: %v\n\n", cert.NotBefore.Format("Jan 2, 2006 3:04 PM"))
        fmt.Printf("Expires: %s\n\n", cert.NotAfter.Format("Jan 2, 2006 3:04 PM"))
        fmt.Printf("Issuer Common Name: %s\n\n", cert.Issuer.CommonName)
        fmt.Println("-----------------------------------------")
    }
    
}
```